# gap between skirting boards and laminate flooring

Tags: laminate-floor, gap, skirting

I put down some laminate flooring with an underlay.
Where the skirting board and flooring meet there is no gap. (for the most part!)

However, where the bed frame legs are up against the wall, the pressure from the legs are pushing the flooring down, and creating a 5mm gap.

Anyway to solve this? or best way to handle it...

Cheers.

[image]

Comment: 5mm seems like a large gap. How thick is your underlay? Is the sub-floor (slab/whatever) flat in that area or is there a dip?

Comment: Was the baseboard existing, or was it installed over the new flooring?

Comment: not sure on underlay thickness, I didn't lay it. skirting was installed after the flooring.